# Cannot register C2DM on device in sample application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I cannot force to work android + appengine example to work on any device. On emulator there was some problems off course, but now everything is working well. On the device all the time I get "failed to register/unregister: email@address". I've done every single step from https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug but it's not going to be better in any way:/